# How else to rewind queue?

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I build this code which displays all entries of an array in queue fashion. The problem is that I was told that this could be done without `for` statement which rewind content of `i` to 0, but I can't figure out how.

How else this could be done?

```
   public void display()
   {
       int i = frontIndex;

       while(true)
       {
           if (i == numberOfItems)
               i = 0;

           System.out.print(array[i++] + " ");

           if (i == rearIndex + 1)
               break;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `%` operator and print the `i % numberOfItems`:

It is not tested, but it should be something along the lines of:

```
for (int i = frontIndex; i % numberOfItems != rearIndex+1; i++) { 
   System.out.print(array[(i++) % numberOfItems)] + " ");
}
```

The idea is `(array.length + k) % array.length == k`, so using the `%` operator, is actually equivalent to resetting the index `i` back to 0.

Comment: +1 the idea is fine but it is not taking "frontIndex" into consideration so the start point of the display will not start from there.

Comment: @A.J.: Thanks, editted. You should start from `i=frontIndex` and not from `i=0`, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Arrays.toString()` method instead of your code if you are just displaying content of array

Comment: `Arrays.toString()` prints the elements starting from 0, the OP wants it starting from arbitrary `frontIndex`.

Comment: then you can create copy of your array using `Arrays.copyOfRange()` in specified range...

Comment: But you will have to take two parts of the array, the one from the frontIndex to the end of the array and an extra one from the 0 element to the rearIndex, and there is a special case where `frontIndex < rearIndex`. It will result in a much more complicated and less efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a `LinkedList` under `Queue` interface. For understanding me better, look at [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) *javadocs*.